# convert Angular function to factory and leverage cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is somewhat different to other questions of similar title.  I am trying to convert a function to a factory to make the data available across controllers however unlike my other similar factories this is not working.

I have other working factories in the same services.js that are working fine. When looking at this in the console they both log the same data so I am wondering if there is something wrong with the `return` not returning correctly?

This works when in the controller only:

Controller

```
getProgrammeData = function(activeProgrammeID) {
    var programmeData = [];
        var GetProgrammeData = Parse.Object.extend("Programme");
        var query = new Parse.Query(GetProgrammeData);
        query.equalTo("objectId", activeProgrammeID);
        query.first({
          success: function(object) {

                   $scope.programmes = {    
                      programmeTitle : object.get('programmeTitle'), 
                      id : object.id,
                      exerciseData : object.get('exerciseData')
                      };

          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });
      }
```

but this does not...

```
services.js



  .factory('parseQueryFactory', function($http) {
        return {
                getProgrammeData:function(activeProgrammeID) {
                var programmeData = [];
                var programmes = {};
                var GetProgrammeData = Parse.Object.extend("Programme");
                var query = new Parse.Query(GetProgrammeData);
                query.equalTo("objectId", activeProgrammeID);
                query.first({
                  success: function(object) {

                                programmes = {    
                              programmeTitle : object.get('programmeTitle'), 
                              id : object.id,
                              exerciseData : object.get('exerciseData')
                              };

                              console.log(programmes)

                  },
                  error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                  }
                })

            return programmes
        }
    }
    });
```

controllers.js

```
$scope.programmes = parseQueryFactory.getProgrammeData(activeProgrammeID);
```

Secondly how am I able to leverage caching of these results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your are returning first an empty object and in the callback of the query, you are creating a new object and loosing reference of that object. Try this:

```
 .factory('parseQueryFactory', function($http) {
        var programmes = {}
        return {
                getProgrammeData:function(activeProgrammeID) {
                var programmeData = [];

                var GetProgrammeData = Parse.Object.extend("Programme");
                var query = new Parse.Query(GetProgrammeData);
                query.equalTo("objectId", activeProgrammeID);
                query.first({
                  success: function(object) {
                      programmes.programmeTitle =object.get('programmeTitle');
                      programmes.id = object.id;
                       programmes.exerciseData = object.get('exerciseData');

                  },
                  error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                  }
                })

            return programmes;
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: I tried to correct the typo in the programmes variable at the top but it wouldn't let me...
My issue came from having many functions within the same factory - so i needed to wrap each in a return.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @JesusQuintana 's answer.

I tend to layout a factory like this:

```
.factory('parseQueryFactory', ['$http', parseQueryFactory])

function parseQueryFactory($http) {
    var service = {
        getProgrammeData: getProgrammeData
    };

    var serviceBase = '/api/someController';

    return service;

    function getProgrammeData(activeProgrammeID) {
        return $http.get(serviceBase, { params: { activeProgrammeID: activeProgrammeID }).then(function (data) {
            return data.data;
        }).catch(function (message) { console.error(message); });
    }
}
```

This then makes it easier on me, when a) I just want to find out what this service  can do, b) what parts of the main function do. E.g. everything before return service is the raw service, and will be the singleton. Everything after are the implementations that my service relies on.